# Using both lists and data extensions at the same time in for email and SMS sending?

Tags: dataextensions, list, data-model

So I know this isn't the best practice but is it possible to use both lists and data extensions in marketing cloud without any complications?

Use case could be like: I use lists when I want to send for specific kind of general audience but I use my master data extension when I want to filter the audience more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very much possible.

Lists have limited functionality, so you will end up using Data Extensions but no issues using either or both of them.